# simplexml loop empty nodes entry for attributes

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have the following XML structure:

```
<parent>
    <child foo="bar1" foo2="bar2"/>
    <child foo="bar3" foo2="bar4"/>
</parent>
```

and in PHP:

```
foreach ($xml->parent->child as $item)
```

returns "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

can I loop through those children with SimpleXML?
and yes there is no space in at the end of the line near to /> .. is that a problem? I just get the data and I have to parse it....

Comment: Is that your full xml? can you provide the code where you instantiate the $xml object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$xml` contains your root node `<parent>`, so do:

```
foreach ($xml->child as $item)
```

the closing tag `/>` is correct.

see https://eval.in/455645